# How to show the subroots (childroots) while clicking on a particular rootnode

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am using devexpress xtratreelist in this I have a tree..now I want my form to work in sucha away that if the user clicks on a particular node all the subroots of that node shud be published on a list box or anyother control..How it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the XtraTreeList control before but taking a quick look at the [online documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/CustomDocument2434.aspx) you should be able to use this [node iteration example](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/CustomDocument5626.aspx) to loop over the relevant nodes and use the TreeListNode parameter to get more details than just simply incrementing the total count.